# Draw heat map on top of a spatial layout image with given coordinates and quantifiable count

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, overlap

Suppose, I have a spacial layout as shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMmeZ.jpg). I have data about a particular quantity (e.g. Temperature or footfalls) on given x, y coordinate locations. So, basically I have three columns, 1. x coordinate, 2. y coordinate, 3. Footfall/Temp. count. I want to generate a heat map for temperature pattern analysis and overlap on my layout. Sample result is shown in image [2]

[image: 1. Sample layout with different sections and 2. Final expected image]

I have tried this thing in R using qplot and mba.surf functions, but I was not able to overlap heat map on layout image. So, I want (preferably R code) to  get results as shown in image [2]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered using `raster` and `sp` packages?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It was my first post, So was not able to add more than 1 image, and could not add results obtained by me.
So far, I have tried qplot, mba.surf for heatmaps. I have also tried using mentioned code in R:  '+ annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)' to overlap heatmap on img (background image). But the overlapping image was taking over background image and only top image could be seen.

Comment: Consider adding example image and data (just simulate some random noise) to your original post. If you have insufficient privilege, put the image somewhere on the internet and ask for it to be inserted into your post by people with sufficient reputation.